# from r code ouput, to rmarkdown input

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I want to take a csv file with name/link, and turn it into a rmarkdown list sorted alphabetically. The sort is easy, the formatting is easy, but going from R output to markdown is confusing.

I have the following csv,

```
name,link
Compiling,compiling.Rmd
Setup,setup.Rmd
Entities,entities.Rmd
```

I then have a R file that sorts the above csv alphabetically and then returns in markdown format (a table of contents).

```
getTOC <- function() {
  toc <- read.csv("data/toc.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
  toc <- toc[order(toc$name),]
  toc$ind <- seq(nrow(toc))

  # into Rmd format
  toc_md <- data.frame(NULL)
  toc_md <- paste0(toc$ind, ". [", toc$name, "](", toc$link, ")\n")
  return(toc_md)
}
```

With the output being:

```
"1. [Compiling](compiling.Rmd)" "2. [Entities](entities.Rmd)"   "3. [Setup](setup.Rmd)"
```

The question feels stupid, but how do I get this output to read into a Rmd file the same way the following would, as any way to output the previous seems to add extra symbols etc which make the .Rmd unreadable.

```
1. [Compiling](compiling.Rmd)
2. [Entities](entities.Rmd)
3. [Setup](setup.Rmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pander` package, which has a bunch of functions for outputting to markdown. One of these is `pandoc.p`, which creates paragraphs for each of the items in the character vector you give it. To print markdown that you've generated, you need to set `results='asis'` for the chunk. So you can use a chunk such as:

````
```{r results='asis'}
toc <- getTOC()
pandoc.p(toc)
```
````

If you keep the markdown, you'll see that this was generated:

```
1. [Compiling](compiling.Rmd)
2. [Entities](entities.Rmd)
3. [Setup](setup.Rmd)
```

which will then knit as you expect to html or latex.

There are other `pandoc.*` functions that might be useful, such as `pandoc.link` and `pandoc.list`.

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help.